# Suppress Image (watermark) in specific section

Tags: crystal-reports

I have an image that has been set as a watermark, however it is also appearing in the report footer section, which is used as the Terms and Conditions page, and I don't want it to appear in that section.

Therefore, can I do a suppression rule on the image to effectively say "if section=reportfooter then true else false"

I just don't know the syntax/if there is one to specify a section of a report?

Many Thanks.

Comment: HAve you place the image in report footer aswell?

Comment: No, it's placed in the page header with Underlay Following Sections ticked.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the Underlay feature of Crystal Reports, the underlay will print with all following sections on top of the section where Underlay is enabled until it reaches the companion section of the report.  This means if you place an image in the Page Header and set the Page Header section to Underlay Following Sections, all of the following sections will print on top of the underlay until the report reaches the Page Footer that corresponds to the Page Header that is using the Underlay feature.  If you have a report with 2 header and footer sections an Underlay that begins in Page Header B will print beneath all section until the Page Footer B section is reach, and this Page Footer B should not have the underlay enabled section printed beneath it.

Do you maybe have multiple headers and footers in your report with the content of your Terms and Conditions printing in a footer that precedes the footer that corresponds the page header where you began your underlay?  For example, if you begin the underlay in Page Header B and placed your Ts&Cs in Page Footer A, then the underlay image would be printed under Footer A, but not under Footer B.  In this scenario moving the content of Footer A into Footer B would place it in a section that isn't printing over the underlay image.

To answer the specific question you asked, you can write a formula to control whether or not a section has the Underlay Following Sections enabled or disable, but this is done in the section where the underlay begins.  To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to control the Underlay feature from a section other than the one that it was enabled within.

You should be able to solve your problem by ensuring you have your sections setup correctly with your content placed in the right sections.  There is one caveat to be aware of when dealing with a section using Underlay though.  It the total height of the section where the Underlay is enable and the sections that follow its companion section are greater than the height of your page size, you will get an error and the report will not print correctly.  It usually turns into a blank two page document when this error occurs.